# MFC: How to copy bitmap using OLE clipboard

Tags: c++, mfc, clipboard, ole

Now I have a `CImage img`, and I wanted to copy the bitmap to the OLE clipboard.

What I did is the following

```
HBITMAP hImage = img.Detach();

CBitmap *pBitmap = CBitmap::FromHandle(hImage);
BITMAP bm;
pBitmap->GetObject(sizeof(bm), &bm);
HBITMAP hImage = Detach();

// the bitmap src
CBitmap *pBitmap = CBitmap::FromHandle(hImage);
BITMAP bm;
pBitmap->GetObject(sizeof(bm), &bm);
// the copy (dest)
CBitmap bitmap; 
bitmap.CreateBitmapIndirect(&bm);
// create mem dc and select src and dest bitmaps
CDC dcMemSrc, dcMemDest;
dcMemSrc.CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
CBitmap* pOldBitmapSrc = dcMemSrc.SelectObject(pBitmap);
dcMemDest.CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
CBitmap* pOldBitmapDest = dcMemDest.SelectObject(&bitmap);
// bit-blt
dcMemDest.BitBlt(0, 0, bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight, &dcMemSrc,
    0, 0, SRCCOPY);
HBITMAP hBitmap = (HBITMAP)bitmap.Detach();
// restore mem dc
dcMemDest.SelectObject(pOldBitmapDest);
dcMemSrc.SelectObject(pOldBitmapSrc);
// Place the copy on the clipboard.
AfxOleInit();
CoInitialize(NULL);
COleDataSource* pods = new COleDataSource;
pods->CacheGlobalData(CF_BITMAP, hBitmap);
pods->SetClipboard();
CoUninitialize();
```

I tested the program, it just doesn't work, I tried to CTRL+V to the Windows Paint program, but it complained the data cannot be pasted in it. If I use the Legacy Clipboard(just replace the last 6 lines with `::OpenClipboard(hWnd)`, `::EmptyClipboard()`, `::SetClipboardData(CF_BITMAP, hBitmap)`, `::CloseClipboard()` ), it works fine. I have no experience working with COM and OLE, can anyone help? Many thanks.

Comment: You don't need to use the OLE clipboard, unless you want to take advantage of its features (e.g. keeping the bitmap linked into the clipboard synced with the original). Looking at your question it seems like you simply want to place the bitmap data into the clipboard without linking it to the original image. No need to make things more complicated here, just keep using the [Clipboard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648709.aspx) API.

Comment: Please refer to
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32309180/why-cant-i-directly-send-an-hbimap-from-a-cimage-to-clipboard